# My teacher is requesting private family life details, is this legal?

Tags: privacy, england-and-wales, human-rights

I live in England. My teacher is requesting private family information as homework. We're studying the play Romeo and Juliet, and she wants us to ask our parents about their dating experiences.

I don't want to do this: she did say she'd be reading them, and it's unclear whether or not she's going to be publicly showing this information.

If I deny her request and she attempts to punish me for it, would that be legal? I was looking at Article 8 on the Human Rights Act 1998, but am not sure if that covers the situation.

Comment: Actually the teacher is asking you to ask your parents about private experiences, which is not a breach of any possible right. *They* can always decline to answer, and *you* do not have any right not to think about your parents' romantic experiences.

Comment: Also, your assignment is to **ask** your parents, but if it's not clear enough, you could specify to them that they can lie if they want...

Comment: So I wouldn't be able to deny her request?

Comment: Technically, no, given the exact words.  However, your parents are free to not answer, and you may want to proceed by asking what to do if they don't and just doing that instead.

Comment: Thing is, I don't really want to ask them. If I tell my teacher this, is she allowed to punish me?